# How to play music from Spotify and local files?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, spotify, music-player

I would like to be able to play music from local files and stream from Spotify. Ideally, cross-fade between tracks is supported (as it is in the official Spotify app). I would also prefer if songs are added to the queue by default. If the queue is cleared when someone clicks on a song, it is not ideal for a party setting where multiple people add songs to the list on the same computer.

Bonus features include: playing songs also from YouTube, maybe even with the video shown in a second window, so it can be displayed on a second screen.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the [Tauon Music Box](https://tauonmusicbox.rocks/) player, which seems to have the features close to what you ask for. Here's how it looks:

[image: Tauon Music Box interface]

Below I will try to address each point in your question.

> I would like to be able to play music from local files and stream from Spotify.

You can go to *MENU* → *Settings* → *Accounts* → *Spotify* and follow the [setup instructions](https://github.com/Taiko2k/TauonMusicBox/wiki/Spotify) that allow for the importing, searching and playback control of Spotify music. It should be noted that this feature only works with Premium Spotify accounts (I don't have one so I haven't actually tested it).

[image: Accounts options]

> Ideally, cross-fade between tracks is supported (as it is in the official Spotify app).

The player by default has cross-fade enabled. You can find the fade settings in *MENU* → *Settings* → *Audio*.

[image: Audio options]

> I would also prefer if songs are added to the queue by default. If the queue is cleared when someone clicks on a song, it is not ideal for a party setting where multiple people add songs to the list on the same computer.

The player doesn't work exactly like that, but it's close. You can add a song to the queue by using <kbd>middle-click</kbd> (alternatively, you can use the <kbd>right-click</kbd> menu or the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut).

If you have added some songs to the queue and you <kbd>double-click</kbd> a song in the library, the queue does not get cleared. Instead, the double-clicked song will be played right away and when the song ends, the songs in the queue will continue playing from where the queue was left.

> Bonus features include: playing songs also from YouTube, maybe even with the video shown in a second window, so it can be displayed on a second screen.

Unfortunately this is not supported nor the player has a feature similar to that.

---

If you like the above and you think that the player fits your needs, you can [install it from Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.taiko2k.tauonmb).